# ASP.NET MVC pasar parametro al hacer click en ActionLink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hola soy novato en el tema,

Deseo pasar un parametro de un controlador a otro controlador , en el momento de realizar la action click enviar el valor de la variable y recibirla al otro controlador ,

Por ejemplo mi primer controlador "Curso" genera vista al seleccionar el curso "matematica " Deseo recibir el controlador "Matricula "el valor "Matematica en el primer input"

por favor su ayuda ,ya que he realizado manualmente una vista por cada curso .
**PAGINA "A"**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pagina "B"**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la vista de la pagina "A" ,al quiero que al darle click me envie a pagina B e inserte el valor en el primer `input`.

```html
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Materia)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Materia)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CursosId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CursosId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CursosId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Controlador de curso

```html
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Cursos.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Cursos/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Cursos cursos = db.Cursos.Find(id);
            if (cursos == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(cursos);
        }
```

Controlador de matricula quiero recibirlo en la variable Curso

```
    // POST: Matriculas/Create
    // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
    // más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MatriculaId,Curso,CursosId")] Matricula matricula)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Matriculas.Add(matricula);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CursosId = new SelectList(db.Cursos, "CursosId", "Materia", matricula.CursosId);
        return View(matricula);
    }
```

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Cursos</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Materia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Materia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Materia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <di@model prueba.Models.Cursos
v class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </di@model>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo.

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código de tus Vistas (A y B) y del **Controlador**.

Comment: ya actualice la publicacion , quiero recibir el parameto en la pagina B en el primer input

Comment: Sigo sin entender que quieres hacer. cuando dices: ".. al darle click en el action link..", a que te refieres? a que ActionLink?. Por favor se más explícito. si no va a ser muy difícil ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Rafael , en la primer vista tengo un html display que muesta una lista de materias .@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Materia .Quiero cambiarlo a un boton que envie el valor del item.materia  y me redirija a otra pagina donde almacene ese valor en un input.

Comment: Actualice la publicacion , espero que quede un poco mas claro .los modelos son solo clases string .

Answer (score 2):

Algo así creo que te puede funcionar

```
@Html.ActionLink("Texto", "miAction", new { id = 1235, parameter = "test" });
```

dentro del objeto anonimo mandas los parametros que tu necesitas separados por coma.

Comment: Como recibe el segundo el parametro ?

Comment: public ActionResult miAction(int id, string parameter){ 
return View();
}